# Is there a way to manually force refresh ionic collection-repeat?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am running into a problem with Ionic `collection-repeat` where the list is not displaying when switching between ion-tabs. However, if the list is refreshed then the items display correctly. I was wondering, is there is a way to force Ionic `collection-repeat` to refresh?

Comment: Ok, so when you switch tabs between the one with the list and one without, when you go back to the one with the list, the list is not there?

Comment: i am assuming that you have caching on... so the controller will not re-render the page.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, both comments above are correct

Answer (score 0):

Can you modify this [codepen](http://codepen.io/bobleujr/pen/bdPzpr) to exemplify your problem? I added a `collection-repeat` inside of an `ion-tab` to facilitate

Thanks